# How to determine the number of arc each region is bounded by?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]
The video says the smallest number of arcs per region is $4$, but to me it seems like it would be $3$? For example, the triangle made by $C,F$ and the intersection of $(F,B) (C,E)$.

Side question, what is the point of $K5$ and $K3,3$

Comment: We don't know which video you mean.

Comment: I added screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge crossing is not allowed.

I would suggest you read up about planar graphs [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph).